# How to conditionally append a data frame row to one above

Tags: r, dataframe, append, row, rows

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
   ID       Date  Period Account                      Amount1 Amount2             
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>                        <chr> <chr>                    
1 76311099 43494 /1     P / ABC / 123456             NA    3116362               
2 NA       NA    NA     C100ST                       NA    NA                         
3 66112599 37135 /26    S / ADR                      NA    1246880.3900000001       
4 NA       NA    NA     65101599 / S0                NA    NA                          
5 45461599 37155 /O6    B / INR / REVERSE            NA    623440.19000000006     
6 NA       NA    NA     UNDO / S0                    NA    NA                
7 69876599 37134 /O3    N / ABC                   401.63   NA        
8 19991099 37122 /O5    P / PDA / ASK 4265        401.65   NA   
9 NA       NA    NA     AT045BT                      NA    NA
```

I've been struggling to get this done but nothing I tried has worked. Basically what I want to do is if the `ID` value of a row is `NA`, I want to append the text in the `Account` column to the row above and then remove it.

I'm expecting the end result to look something like this:

```
   ID      Date  Period Account                      Amount1 Amount2             
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>                        <chr> <chr>                    
1 76311099 43494 /1     P / ABC / 123456 / C100ST     NA    3116362                                     
2 66112599 37135 /26    S / ADR / 65101599 / S0       NA    1246880.3900000001                       
3 45461599 37155 /O6    B / INR / REVERSE / UNDO / S0 NA    623440.19000000006                
4 69876599 37134 /O3    N / ABC                       401.63   NA        
5 19991099 37122 /O5    P / PDA / ASK 4265 / AT045BT  401.65   NA
```

As you can see, the Row with `ID` value `69876599` remains the same as there was no other row immediately below it with a `NA` value for `ID`.

Does anyone know a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option would be to `fill` the selected column to change the `NA` with the previous non-NA element, grouped by those columns, collapse the 'Account' by concatenating the elements to a single string, then `summarise` the rest of the 'Amount' columns to get the first non-NA element

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   fill(ID, Date, Period) %>%
   group_by(ID, Date, Period) %>%
   group_by(Account = str_c(Account, collapse = ' / '), add = TRUE) %>%
   summarise_all(list(~ .[which(!is.na(.))[1]]))
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   ID, Date, Period [5]
#        ID  Date Period Account                       Amount1  Amount2
#     <int> <int> <chr>  <chr>                           <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 19991099 37122 /O5    P / PDA / ASK 4265 / AT045BT     402.      NA 
#2 45461599 37155 /O6    B / INR / REVERSE / UNDO / S0     NA   623440.
#3 66112599 37135 /26    S / ADR / 65101599 / S0           NA  1246880.
#4 69876599 37134 /O3    N / ABC                          402.      NA 
#5 76311099 43494 /1     P / ABC / 123456 / C100ST         NA  3116362
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(76311099L, NA, 66112599L, NA, 45461599L, 
NA, 69876599L, 19991099L, NA), Date = c(43494L, NA, 37135L, NA, 
37155L, NA, 37134L, 37122L, NA), Period = c("/1", NA, "/26", 
NA, "/O6", NA, "/O3", "/O5", NA), Account = c("P / ABC / 123456", 
"C100ST", "S / ADR", "65101599 / S0", "B / INR / REVERSE", "UNDO / S0", 
"N / ABC", "P / PDA / ASK 4265", "AT045BT"), Amount1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 401.63, 401.65, NA), Amount2 = c(3116362, 
NA, 1246880.39, NA, 623440.19, NA, NA, NA, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a base-R solution...

Let d = your data frame,

```
i <- which(is.na(d[,1]))
d[i-1,"Account"] <- paste(d[i-1,"Account"],d[i,"Account"])
d <- d[-i,]
```